# error after deleting wrong model file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am getting this error when I try to create a new GroupLink

### Controller code:

```
def new
  @group_links=GroupLink.new
  respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render(:template=> 'group_links/new_link_details', :layout =>      
  '/layouts/sponsored_group_manage_sub_menu') }
  end
end

 def create
   @group_link=GroupLink.new(params[:group_link])
   @group_link.group_id=params[:group_id]
    if @group_link.save
    flash[:notice] = "A new booth link was created!"
     else
    flash[:errors] = @group_link.errors
   end
   redirect_to group_group_links_path(@group)
  end
```

### The model relationship is a one-to-many association:

```
 class GroupLink < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :group
    validates_presence_of :url
    validates_presence_of :text

 def link
   self.url
 end

 def text
  self.text
 end
end

 class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :group_links, :dependent => :destroy
 end
```

### The routes file has the following:

```
resources :groups do
 member do
  get :get_group_links
 end

 resources :group_links
 ...
end
```

### The view file is as follows:

```
  <% content_for(:page_title, "Create a New Booth Link") -%>
  <% form_for(:group_link,:url => group_group_links_path, :html => {:id => 
    "new_group_link", :method => :post}) do |f| %>
  <fieldset>
 <h6>New Booth Link</h6>
  <label for="group_link_url">URL</label><br />
  <%= f.text_field :url, :size => 32, :placeholder => "URL for the booth link" %><br    
      /><br />
  <label for="group_link_text">Text</label><br />
  <%= f.text_field :text, :size => 32, :placeholder => "The text for this booth 
     link" %><br/><br />
     <div class="buttons">
 <%= f.submit "Create Booth Link", :class => "button large" %>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
 <% end %>
```

The problem started when I mistakenly created the model as group_links instead of group_link.SO I rolled back the migration and destroyde the model and recreated it with the correct name. AFter I made this change it started throwing this error (it was creating the new group links with the group_links model correctly, but as expected the routes wnet haywire so i decided to change it)

Please help, I just cannot make out what the issue is....

Below is the full stack trace:

> ```
> app/models/group_link.rb:12:in `text'
> app/models/group_link.rb:12:in `text' activemodel (3.0.20) lib/active_model/errors.rb:224:in `read_attribute_for_validation'
> ```
>
> activemodel (3.0.20) lib/active_model/errors.rb:224:in `send'
>   activemodel (3.0.20) lib/active_model/errors.rb:224:in`add_on_blank'
>   activemodel (3.0.20) lib/active_model/errors.rb:223:in `each'
>   activemodel (3.0.20) lib/active_model/errors.rb:223:in`add_on_blank'
>   activemodel (3.0.20) lib/active_model/validations/presence.rb:9:in
>   `validate' activesupport (3.0.20)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:315:in`send' activesupport (3.0.20)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:315:in `_callback_before_7973'
>   activesupport (3.0.20) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:420:in`
>   _run_validate_callbacks' activemodel (3.0.20)
>   lib/active_model/validations.rb:212:in `run_validations!' activemodel
>   (3.0.20) lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:67:in`
>   run_validations!' activesupport (3.0.20)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:419:in `_run_validation_callbacks'
>   activemodel (3.0.20) lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:67:in`
>   run_validations!' activemodel (3.0.20)
>   lib/active_model/validations.rb:179:in `valid?' activerecord (3.0.20)
>   lib/active_record/validations.rb:55:in`valid?' activerecord (3.0.20)
>   lib/active_record/validations.rb:75:in `perform_validations'
>   activerecord (3.0.20) lib/active_record/validations.rb:43:in`save'
>   activerecord (3.0.20)
>   lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:21:in `save' activerecord
>   (3.0.20) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:240:in`save' activerecord
>   (3.0.20) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:292:in
>   `with_transaction_returning_status' activerecord (3.0.20)
>   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:139:in`
>   transaction' activerecord (3.0.20)
>   lib/active_record/transactions.rb:207:in
>   `transaction_without_trace_ActiveRecord_self_name_transaction'
>   newrelic_rpm (3.3.4.1) lib/new_relic/agent/method_tracer.rb:491:in`
>   transaction' newrelic_rpm (3.3.4.1)
>   lib/new_relic/agent/method_tracer.rb:242:in `trace_execution_scoped'
>   newrelic_rpm (3.3.4.1) lib/new_relic/agent/method_tracer.rb:486:in`
>   transaction' activerecord (3.0.20)
>   lib/active_record/transactions.rb:290:in
>   `with_transaction_returning_status' activerecord (3.0.20)
>   lib/active_record/transactions.rb:240:in`save' activerecord (3.0.20)
>   lib/active_record/transactions.rb:251:in
>   `rollback_active_record_state!' activerecord (3.0.20)
>   lib/active_record/transactions.rb:239:in`save'
>   app/controllers/group_links_controller.rb:23:in `create' actionpack
>   (3.0.20) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in`
>   send_action' actionpack (3.0.20)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
>   actionpack (3.0.20) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:150:in`
>   process_action' actionpack (3.0.20)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:11:in `process_action'
>   actionpack (3.0.20) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in`
>   process_action' activesupport (3.0.20)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:511:in
>   `_run__584584438__process_action__43712543__callbacks' activesupport
>   (3.0.20) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:410:in`send' activesupport
>   (3.0.20) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:410:in
>   `_run_process_action_callbacks' activesupport (3.0.20)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:94:in`send' activesupport (3.0.20)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:94:in `run_callbacks' actionpack
>   (3.0.20) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in`process_action'
>   actionpack (3.0.20) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in
>   `process_action' actionpack (3.0.20)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in`process_action'
>   activesupport (3.0.20) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in
>   `instrument' activesupport (3.0.20)
>   lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in`instrument'
>   activesupport (3.0.20) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in
>   `instrument' actionpack (3.0.20)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in`process_action'
>   newrelic_rpm (3.3.4.1)
>   lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/rails3/action_controller.rb:34:in
>   `process_action' newrelic_rpm (3.3.4.1)
>   lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/controller_instrumentation.rb:255:in`
>   perform_action_with_newrelic_trace' newrelic_rpm (3.3.4.1)
>   lib/new_relic/agent/method_tracer.rb:242:in `trace_execution_scoped'
>   newrelic_rpm (3.3.4.1)
>   lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/controller_instrumentation.rb:250:in`
>   perform_action_with_newrelic_trace' newrelic_rpm (3.3.4.1)
>   lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/rails3/action_controller.rb:33:in
>   `process_action' actionpack (3.0.20)
>   lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:119:in`process' actionpack (3.0.20)
>   lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:41:in `process' actionpack
>   (3.0.20) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:138:in`dispatch' actionpack
>   (3.0.20) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in
>   `dispatch' actionpack (3.0.20) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:178:in`
>   action' actionpack (3.0.20)
>   lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:68:in `call' actionpack
>   (3.0.20) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:68:in`dispatch'
>   actionpack (3.0.20) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:33:in
>   `call' rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:148:in`call'
>   rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:93:in
>   `recognize' rack-mount (0.6.14)
>   lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:131:in`optimized_each' rack-mount
>   (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:92:in `recognize'
>   rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:139:in`call'
>   actionpack (3.0.20) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:499:in
>   `call' newrelic_rpm (3.3.4.1)
>   lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:23:in`call' newrelic_rpm
>   (3.3.4.1) lib/new_relic/rack/developer_mode.rb:24:in `call' sass
>   (3.2.5) lib/sass/./sass/plugin/rack.rb:54:in`call' warden (1.0.6)
>   lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `call' warden (1.0.6)
>   lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in`catch' warden (1.0.6)
>   lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call' actionpack (3.0.20)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in`call'
>   actionpack (3.0.20) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in
>   `call' rack (1.2.7) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in`call' actionpack
>   (3.0.20) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
>   actionpack (3.0.20) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:182:in`
>   call' actionpack (3.0.20)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:149:in `call'
>   actionpack (3.0.20) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:302:in`
>   call' activerecord (3.0.20) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in
>   `call' activerecord (3.0.20)
>   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:28:in`
>   cache' activerecord (3.0.20) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:12:in
>   `cache' activerecord (3.0.20) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31:in`
>   call' activerecord (3.0.20)
>   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:354:in
>   `call' actionpack (3.0.20)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:46:in`call' activesupport
>   (3.0.20) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:416:in `_run_call_callbacks'
>   actionpack (3.0.20) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44:in`
>   call' rack (1.2.7) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:106:in `call' actionpack
>   (3.0.20) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in`call'
>   actionpack (3.0.20)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
>   railties (3.0.20) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in`call' rack (1.2.7)
>   lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call' activesupport (3.0.20)
>   lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in`call' rack
>   (1.2.7) lib/rack/lock.rb:13:in `call' rack (1.2.7)
>   lib/rack/lock.rb:13:in`synchronize' rack (1.2.7)
>   lib/rack/lock.rb:13:in `call' actionpack (3.0.20)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30:in`call' railties
>   (3.0.20) lib/rails/application.rb:168:in `call' railties (3.0.20)
>   lib/rails/application.rb:77:in`send' railties (3.0.20)
>   lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing' railties (3.0.20)
>   lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in`call' rack (1.2.7)
>   lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call' rack (1.2.7)
>   lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:52:in`service'
>   /home/vasu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in
>   `service'
>   /home/vasu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in`
>   run'
>   /home/vasu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in
>   `start_thread'
>   /home/vasu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in`
>   start'
>   /home/vasu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in
>   `start_thread'
>   /home/vasu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in`
>   start'
>   /home/vasu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in
>   `each'
>   /home/vasu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in`
>   start'
>   /home/vasu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in
>   `start'
>   /home/vasu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in`
>   start' rack (1.2.7) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:13:in `run' rack
>   (1.2.7) lib/rack/server.rb:217:in`start' railties (3.0.20)
>   lib/rails/commands/server.rb:65:in `start' railties (3.0.20)
>   lib/rails/commands.rb:30 railties (3.0.20) lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in`
>   tap' railties (3.0.20) lib/rails/commands.rb:27 script/rails:6:in
>   `require' script/rails:6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue that I see is the method in `GroupLink`

```
 def text
  self.text
 end
```

You are defining the method `text` that is just calling itself.  Try deleting this method.

Comment: Agreed. Also the two methods themselves are redundant. The OP just need to set `attr_accessible: url, txt`. That's enough.

Comment: Yes, this was the issue...removed the methods and its working fine now! Many thanks to you guys!....